# Pyserial can't read device

Tags: python, serial-port, hardware, pyserial

I'm trying to read data off of a sensor that I bought, using a conversion module (SSI to RS232).  I have the module plugged into my Windows laptop via USB/serial converter.

When I use Putty in Serial mode, I can send the command $2RD and receive the appropriate response from the sensor unit.  When I run a script to try to do the same thing, the unit returns: ''

Here is the code I am using:

```
import sys
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial(
    port='COM4', 
    baudrate=9600, 
    timeout=1,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
)  

while True:
    ser.write('$2RD'.encode())
    #time.sleep(1)
    s = ser.read(26)
    print s
```

A few other notes:

- I've tried some variations using flushInput, flushOutput, sleeping, waiting, etc...nothing seems to help.
- I know I have the COM ports right/the hardware all works in Putty, so pretty sure this is something with my code.
- I've also tries 13,400 BAUD with no difference in outcome.
- If I connect the TX and RX lines from the USB, I can read the command I'm sending...so it should be at least getting to the RS232/SSI conversion device.

Comment: Just to be clear the unit returns an empty string ' ' ?

Comment: Yes.  It returns a blank or ' ' (empty string)

Answer (score 0):

`s = ser.read(26)` should probably be `ser.read(size=26)` since it takes keyword argument and not positional argument.

Also, you can try to set a timeout to see what was sent after a specific time because otherwise the function can block if 26 bytes aren't sent as specified in the read docs of pyserial :

> Read size bytes from the serial port. If a timeout is set it may return less characters as requested. With no timeout it will block until the requested number of bytes is read.

Comment: Adding size= did not have any affect on the outcome (still reading the same thing)

timeout is set to 1.  Upping it to 5 doesn't do anything by make it take longer to read.  It's like there's nothing there (but there should be)

Comment: Try first to remove the while true loop while putting the sleep and flushing the buffer.

Comment: Is there an order to the flushing?  I basically just ran this, with the same outcome as always:

`import sys`
`import serial`
`import time`

`ser = serial.Serial(`
    `port='COM4',` 
    `baudrate=9600,` 
    `timeout=1,`
    `parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,`
    `stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,`
    `bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,`
`)`  

`ser.flushInput()`    
`ser.flushOutput()`

    `ser.write('$2RD'.encode())`
    `time.sleep(1)`
    `s = ser.read(size=26)`
    `print s`

I also tried moving the flushes around to some places that make logical sense, with no change